# Pop up modal immediately disappear

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcyjV.png)

The image is showing the data in the table.

What I want is when I click the view button, it will pop up the modal to display the row of data.

I want get the row of data and display in the pop up modal.
After I added this script, the modal will pop up and close directly.
The modal cannot show, the modal just display one second and close directly

script code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.resetbtn').on('click', function() {
            $('#resetmodal').modal('show');
            $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var data = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
                return $(this).text();
            }).get();
            console.log(data);
            $('#pass_id').val(data[0]);
        });
    });
```

button code

```
<button type="button" style="border:none; background-color: transparent;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resetmodal" class="resetbtn">view<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" style="font-size:15px; color:blue;"></i></button> |
```

modal code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="resetmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><b>RESET PASSWORD</b></h3>
            </div>
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input name="pass_id" id="pass_id" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $db_pass_id; ?>"></input>
                        </div>             
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><b>Password : </b></label> &nbsp;<span class="validation">*</span>
                            <input name="p_password3" id="p_password3" type="password" class="form-control input-box" onkeypress="return AvoidSpace(event)" onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" minlength="6" required></input>
                            <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction3()">&nbsp; Show Password</input>   
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label><b>Confirm Password : </b></label> &nbsp;<span class="validation">*</span>
                            <input name="p_password4" id="p_password4" type="password" class="form-control input-box" onkeypress="return AvoidSpace(event)" onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);" minlength="6" required></input>
                            <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction4()">&nbsp; Show Password</input>            
                        </div>                                  
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" name="reset" class="btn btn-primary">RESET</button>
                        <button type="button" name="close" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well it is working fine

Comment: did you try to remove  " data-target="#resetmodal" " from button code.

Comment: after remove data-target="#resetmodal" , its work. Thanks, but why ?

Comment: are you getting any console error ?

Answer (score 0):

data-target="#resetmodal" does the show/hide for you!. But inside your script you have

```
$('#resetmodal').modal('show');
```

In other words, you are showing modal with that script and hiding with data-target="#resetmodal"